# How to input concurrent queries from a Python handler to C-function and redirect the output back to Python?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, sockets

I have my Web Application in a Python framework. And I have written a C function for a complicated computation. I want to pass the query received by Python Handler as an argument to my C function and render the result in HTML.

It's not just about calling a C-function from Python, but also there are many parallel requests from Python, and there is a common resource that all 'C-threads' should share.

Instead of C, if I had used Java, I would do this using Sockets and Java multi-threading to handle concurrent requests from Python handler.

How can I do similar thing in C? Is there a multi-threading library & socket library for Python to C? What is the standard way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Python is written in C, and there is a very complete [C-API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) which you can use to write your own Python/C functions. Unfortunately, due to the GIL (global interpreter lock) python will never have a light multithreading interface, but so long as you're careful with what you return there are none of these limits in the C-API.

If this doesn't appeal, common alternatives include [cython](http://www.cython.org/) or [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

> Cython is a language that makes writing C extensions for the Python language as easy as Python itself.

whilst

> ctypes is a foreign function library for Python. It provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries. It can be used to wrap these libraries in pure Python.